# Is there an API for the chrome://webrtc-internals/ variables in javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webrtc, google-chrome-app, peerjs

I want to get access to some of the logged variables in the `chrome://webrtc-internals/`, but I didn't find anything on google - not even a description of the graphs I can see.
I am particularly interested in `packetsLost`, `googCurrentDelayMs` and `googNacksSent`.

**why I want to access the webrtc-internals**
I am writing a *google chrome application* that shares a video stream (p2p). It uses [peerjs](http://peerjs.com/) to share the stream with other peers, which in turn uses googles **webrtc** implementation underneath. To make my application perfect I would need to know when a big delay occurs. Since I can see the delay logged in `chrome://webrtc-internals/` I was wondering if I could access it through javascript.

My guess is there is no API for the `chrome://webrtc-internals/`-menu.

Comment: @xan do you think the answer is incomplete?

Comment: Quite the opposite - it's just a 24h cooldown until I can award the bounty.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I found it - had to crawl through a couple of google community-threads([thread 1](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-reviews/jOpDoUZYVVg), [thread2](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/discuss-webrtc/uQhlEl3DT4o)):

```
var peerjs = new Peer(...);  // initialize peerJS
var connections = peerjs.connections;
```

Connections is an object:

```
Object {2e1c5694-e6ef-e1b2-22d5-84a3807961d4: Array[3]}
    2e1c5694-e6ef-e1b2-22d5-84a3807961d4: Array[3]
        0: DataConnection
        1: MediaConnection
        2: MediaConnection
        length: 3
    __proto__: Array[0]
__proto__: Object
```

Take a look at any of those connection objects:

```
var rtcPeerConn = connectionObject.pc; // RTCPeerConnection

rtcPeerConn.getStats(function callback(connStats){
    var rtcStatsReports = connStats.result() // array of available status-reports
    // each status-report object has many status variables, such as
    // googCurrentDelayMs. You need to iterate over all object and check 
    // their names to find the one status report you want
    rtcStatsReports[7].names() // returns all available variables for that report

    var googCurrentDelayMs = rtcStatsReports[7].stat('googCurrentDelayMs')
    console.log(googCurrentDelayMs) // finally - googCurrentDelayMs :-)
})
```

Comment: wow been looking for this info! Very hard to find stuff on getStat(). Do you know what exactly the 'googCurrentDelayMS' is measuring?

Comment: as far as I can derive from its name the delay (in ms) of that respective stream you are looking at. As far as I can tell its the grand total delay of the stream - but I am actually using some other variables now that were more valuable to my application - lost packets to figure out when the stream is blocked.

Answer (score 2):

Afer researching a lot, this is how I managed to get the pc using twilio SDK.

```
var rtcPeerConn =Twilio.Device.activeConnection();
rtcPeerConn.options.mediaStreamFactory.protocol.pc.getStats(function callback(report) {
                var rtcStatsReports = report.result();
                for (var i=0; i<rtcStatsReports.length; i++) {
                    var statNames = rtcStatsReports[i].names();
                    // filter the ICE stats
                    if (statNames.indexOf("transportId") > -1) {
                        var logs = "";
                        for (var j=0; j<statNames.length; j++) {
                            var statName = statNames[j];
                            var statValue = rtcStatsReports[i].stat(statName);
                            logs = logs + statName + ": " + statValue + ", ";
                        }
                        console.log(logs);
                    }
                }
            });
```

//Calculate errorRate   Packetlost / packetsent

```
var rtcPeerConn =Twilio.Device.activeConnection();
rtcPeerConn.options.mediaStreamFactory.protocol.pc.getStats(function callback(report) {
                var error, pcksent;
                var rtcStatsReports = report.result();
                for (var i=0; i<rtcStatsReports.length; i++) {
                    var statNames = rtcStatsReports[i].names();
                    // filter the ICE stats
                    if (statNames.indexOf("packetsSent") > -1) {
                        var logs = "";
                        for (var j=0; j<statNames.length; j++) {
                            var statName = statNames[j];
                            var statValue = rtcStatsReports[i].stat(statName);
                            if(statName=="packetsLost")
                              error= statValue;
                            if(statName =="packetsSent")
                              pcksent = statValue;
                            logs = logs +"n:" +statName + ": " + statValue + ", ";
                        }
                        console.log(error/pcksent);
                    }
                }

            });
```

Comment: Does this work with calls made through twillio's servers or work for any ongoing webrtc traffic on my browser?