# Enable users of a WebRtc app to download webrtc logs via javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, webrtc, electron, chromium

I've seen the following:

```
chrome://webrtc-internals
```

However I'm looking for a way to let users click a button from within the web app to either download or - preferably - `POST` WebRtc logs to an endpoint baked into the app.  The idea is that I can enable non-technical users to share technical logs with me through the click of a UI button.

How can this be achieved?

Note: This should not be dependent on Chrome; Chromium will also be used as the app will be wrapped up in Electron.

Comment: Perhaps this answer should help: [Is there an API for the `chrome://webrtc-internals/` variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24070353/165674)

Comment: @DheerajV.S. thanks - using that I built a little stats extractor posted below.

Answer (score 3):

This is what I ended up using (replace knockout with underscore or whatever):

```
            connectionReport.signalingState = connection.signalingState;
            connectionReport.stats = [];
            connection.getStats(function (stats) {
                const reportCollection = stats.result();
                ko.utils.arrayForEach(reportCollection, function (innerReport) {
                    const statReport = {};
                    statReport.id = innerReport.id;
                    statReport.type = innerReport.type;
                    const keys = innerReport.names();
                    ko.utils.arrayForEach(keys, function (reportKey) {
                        statReport[reportKey] = innerReport.stat(reportKey);
                    })
                    connectionReport.stats.push(statReport);
                });
                connectionStats.push(connectionReport);
            });
```

**UPDATE:**

It appears that this `getStats` mechanism is soon-to-be-deprecated.

Answer (score 3):

You need to write a javascript equivalent that captures all RTCPeerConnection API calls. [rtcstats.js](https://github.com/opentok/rtcstats) does that but sends all data to a server. If you replace that behaviour with storing it in memory you should be good.

Comment: What are your thoughts on the solution I posted?  Would this give the insights needed to debug the majority of WebRTC issues?

Comment: In most cases I have seen the API trace was more helpful than the getStats result -- see https://testrtc.com/webrtc-api-trace/. Also you're using the legacy chrome stats api which should be avoided.

Comment: Do you have an example that demonstrates how to dump these logs clientside (or even how to use that at all - I'm not seeing much documented around configuration there)?  I think that would be most helpful for future readers.

Comment: I pushed a commit [here](https://github.com/opentok/rtcstats/tree/clientside) -- essentially build the bundled version using npm run dist, then create a peerconnection on the included test page and inspect window.rtcstats.connections

Comment: I hate to be a pain - but I'm still not clear.  I think having a self-contained example of how to `require` this and use it without a dependency on building node (or some external server) would help more people; as would having any relevant code in the answer.   Totally get it if you don't have time for this - I can try to figure it out and post up if that's the case.  I think the most common use case here would be "Allow me to log these (or access these) logs clientside so I can decide what to do with them."  A clear example of setting that up would surely help anyone else looking for this.

Answer (score 0):

Reading through js source of `chrome://webrtc-internals`, I noticed that the web page is using a method called `chrome.send()` to send messages like `chrome.send('enableEventLogRecordings');`, to execute logging commands.
According to [here](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-dev/WjuH8bFW5k0):

> chrome.send() is a private function only available to internal chrome
>   pages.

so the function is sandboxed which makes accessing to it not possible