# How do multiplayer javascript games communicate with servers?

Tags: javascript

how do online javascript games like agar.io, slither.io and all the other ".io" games communicate with their servers? I opened the Network tab on google chrome but no requests were there. Does google chrome hide these requests or do these websites use a different protocol?

Comment: They don't.  They just simulate other users.   Prove it to yourself by launching the game and disconnecting your network cable.

Comment: @RainbowDash No, those users are not simulated. I'm able to play with my friends on some of these websites. When I disconnect from the network it says "You have been disconnected" and the game stops.

Comment: PSA: Your browser dev tools won't hide requests from you unless you specifically filter them out yourself.

Comment: It's likely to be one of: Plain HTTP(S), WebSockets or WebRTC. I believe the first two would appear by default in the network panel, so you might gain more info by visiting the `chrome://webrtc-internals` page. [Further reading](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17531831)

Comment: @spender I never knew that WebRTC was used for this kind of stuff. Thank you so much :)

Comment: @Dtomper If you want to learn more, I suggest that direct your attention to [`RTCDataChannel`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCDataChannel) and fan-out from there. To get this kind of set-up for p2p communication working requires ICE/STUN servers. These are non-trivial to set-up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely WebSockets. For example, in agar.io if you go into the chrome network tab you can see a WebSocket request:

[image]

Clicking on it we see the following WebSocket packets being transmitted and receieved:

[image]

The green being transmitted packets, and the red being received packets. If you click on one of those packets you can see a hex dump of the packet. If you want to learn more about WebSockets you can go [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API). A good WebSocket library is socket.io which you can learn  about [here](https://socket.io/).